# How to move VSTS build and release definitions from one instance to another instance?

Tags: azure-devops

We have many VSTS instances,We are trying to consolidate multiple VSTS instances into 1.For that we need to move all the build and release definitions to one particular instance.Please help me out on this.I want the procedure how to proceed on this.I tried from google but not getting any solutions.Please help me out.I am new to VSTS.

Comment: If you have less build/release definitions to move, you can also use the feature export/import build and release definitions in the web page.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the [REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-5.0).

First, make sure both instances have the same build/release task extensions installed.

The process, then, would be:

- Retrieve a build definition
- Update the build definition to use the appropriate agent queue in the target instance
- Import the build definition and note the build definition ID
- Repeat for all build definitions
- Retrieve a release definition
- Update each environment in the release to use the appropriate agent queue in the target instance
- Update the artifacts to point to the appropriate, newly-import build definition(s) (using the IDs from the previous step)
- Import the release definition
- Repeat for all release definitions

You may also have to update approvers or something similar. Basically, it's going to be a trial-and-error process.

Comment: ,I am not understanding the procedure which you are telling here.I just went through RestAPI page there what kind of data I need to capture or follow ?Please explain to me as I am new to REST API as well..

Answer (score 0):

You can export the build and export the release.

**Export build definition**

[image]

**Export release definition**

[image]

On your target team project, you can import your exported files.

**Import build definition**

On the builds hub:

[image]

**Import release definition**

[image]

Note that after importing you will need to point your release to the correct artifacts, but this is a small step, just changing the artifact to use the new one.

Comment: if I import into another VSTS instance the old VSTS URL's in the exported Json file will still exist and some other settings also we need to remove.If we won't remove those stuff new VSTS instance is not allowing to import into it.Throwing error like json file is not valid.Please export Json file again and import it.So the question here is any idea how to import and export build and release definitions easily from one VSTS instance to another Instance without modifying Json file.

Comment: Without some modifications, doing it the way I explained, it is not possible. But consider how many times you will do this. If it is a recurring task, then automate it would be better, but you could have more effort to build your automation. If it is a one time job, then you could have less effort just changing the json.